# Printing out a Dynamic Arrays filled with pointers pointing to classes not printing out correct print function?

Tags: visual-c++

So, I have a homework problem with these steps:
1. Prompt the user for the number of people to create, then create an array of personType pointers to hold them.

2. Loop through the array, prompting the user to decide whether to create a personType,r studentType, and professorType and enter the data as necessary, then use appropriate new  constructor.
3. Finally, loop through the array again and call the (virtual) print method for each person.
4. Delete the objects, deallocate the array and quit.

In this program, there are already 3 classes: personType, studentType, and professorType. studentType and professorType are derived from personType. Each of them has their own void print() function, with studentType and professorType print() funtions overriding personType print(). Yet, when I try to print, I can only seem to call personType print() method.

I have tried rewriting my code to use the constructors to populate each pointer in the array of pointers. I have also tried making personType print() method function protected, and adding a virtual print() method (though I don't think I fully understand virtual functions yet).

```
#include "personType.h"
#include "studentType.h"
#include "professorType.h"
int main()
{
    int num;
    personType **people;

    string fName;
    string lName;
    string address;
    double height;
    string DOB;
    char gender;

    string id;
    double gpa;
    string classification;

    string employeeID;
    string department;
    string degree;

    int choice;

    cout << "Please enter the amount of people you wish to create: ";
    cin >> num;
    while (cin.fail()) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(256, '/n');
        cout << "Please enter the amount of people you wish to create: ";
        cin >> num;
    }
    people = new personType *[num];
    system("pause");
    system("cls");

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        cout << "1 - Person, 2 - Student, and 3 - Professor" << endl;
        cout << "Enter the type of person you wish to create: ";
        cin >> choice;
        while (cin.fail() && choice < 1 && choice > 3) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(256, '/n');
            cout << "Enter the type of person you wish to create (1-3): ";
            cin >> choice;
        }

        cout << "Person " << i + 1 << endl;
        cout << "First Name: ";
        cin >> fName;

        cout << "Last Name: ";
        cin >> lName;

        cout << "Address: ";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(1, '/n');
        getline(cin, address);

        cout << "Height (inches): ";
        cin >> height;
        while (cin.fail()) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(256, '/n');
            cout << "Height (inches): ";
            cin >> height;
        }

        cout << "Date of Birth: ";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(1, '/n');
        getline(cin, DOB);

        cout << "Gender: ";
        cin >> gender;
        while (cin.fail()) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(256, '/n');
            cout << "Gender: ";
            cin >> gender;
        }

        if (choice == 2)
        {
            cout << "ID: ";
            cin >> id;

            cout << "Classification: ";
            cin >> classification;

            cout << "GPA: ";
            cin >> gpa;
            while (cin.fail()) {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(1, '/n');
                cout << "GPA: ";
                cin >> gpa;
            }

            people[i] = new studentType(fName, lName, address, height, DOB, gender, gpa, classification, id);
        }
        else if (choice == 3)
        {
            people[i] = new professorType();

            cout << "Employee ID: ";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(1, '/n');
            cin >> employeeID;

            cout << "Department: ";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(1, '/n');
            getline(cin, department);

            cout << "Degree: ";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(1, '/n');
            getline(cin, degree);

            people[i] = new professorType(fName, lName, address, height, DOB, gender, employeeID, department, degree);
        }
        else {
            people[i] = new personType(fName, lName, address, height, DOB, gender);
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
    system("cls");

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        people[i]->print();
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        delete people[i];
    delete[] people;
}
```

I can only print from the personType print function, instead of calling studentType and professor type print functions when needed.

Comment: My guess would be, `personType::print` is not in fact declared `virtual`.

Comment: It is defined as virtual, yet for some reason visual studio is not recognizing the polymorphism in my code